# how to make a line break in a text object from an external file

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object, external-applications

So I am controlling a test object's text property from an external text file with this code

```
def text():
    import bge
    from bge import logic
    path = logic.expandPath('//')

    cont= logic.getCurrentController()
    scene= logic.getCurrentScene()
    own= cont.owner
    T= int(own['t']) 

    try:
        file = open(path+'text_file.txt', 'r')
        info = file.readlines()
        own.text = info[T]
    except:
        print('error')
```

it works fine except for if I want line breaks so it doesn't stretch off the box i have it in. for example i have the veriable 't' set to 0 and the first line of the txt doc says "example text for stuff" but i want a line break between "text" and "for". If i was setting the normal text vaule and wanted a break there i'd have the code

```
own.text='example text\nfor stuff'
```

but if i type that in the txt file it just displays the line break command (\n). how do i make a line break command from inside the txt file be recognized  by python? or is it even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

When the text file is read, no interpretation is made of what is written, is just text.
For that reason yo sould write in the text file as: `own.text = 'write it in \na new line'` and then in your script use [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

```
from bge import logic

def text():
    path = logic.expandPath('//')
    cont= logic.getCurrentController()
    scene= logic.getCurrentScene()
    own= cont.owner

    try:
        file = open(path+'text_file.txt', 'r')
        info = file.readlines()
        exec(info[0])
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('error', e)
```

**Disclaimer**

**CAUTION**

This is as dangerous as someone writing "wipeout this pc" and boom... your info is gone!.